# Solspace tag - display entries for multiple tags

Tags: channel-entries, tags, solspace-tag

How can I display entries for multiple tags?

For example http://www.my-domain.com/products/by-tag/color/blue+red+white should to display all entries which were tagged with blue and red and white "color tags"

I have try to split last segment by "+" and then loop through that array as separate `{exp:tag:entries channel="products" tag="<?php echo $tag; ?>"}` but final result is kind of messy, especially when multiple pages were returned.

Comment: @Solspace  So no statement or even solution on that matter? Extension can't handle multiple tags or what (bug)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to list entries tagged with your three tags using `{exp:tag:entries}` and the [`tag_separator=""`](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/entries/#tag_separator) parameter. For example:

```
{exp:tag:entries
  channel="products"
  tag_separator="+"
  marker="color"
}
```

The default is a **comma**. If you want tags to be separated by a `+`, then use `tag_separator="+"`. In some cases, depending on your server and htaccess file settings, the `+` is actually read as a space, so if the above doesn't work try `tag_separator=" "`.

The [`marker=""`](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/entries/#marker) parameter can be used when having Tag dynamically determine the tags from the URI, which would be detected using another URI marker rather than the standard `tag` marker segment. As an example using your case, insead of `template/tag/my_tag` it would be `template/color/my_tag`. Think of it as the `category` marker segment in EE for {exp:channel:entries}.