# Solspce Tag and pagination

Tags: solspace-tag, pagination

Based on Solcpase Tag [documentation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/entries/#tag_paginate)

> Pagination is available for this tag and works just like regular EE
>   pagination, but each variable/variable pair is prepended with tag_
>   (except for any variables/variable pairs inside of the
>   tag_pagination_links variable pair). Used in conjunction with the
>   paginate parameter.

so I have converted working pagination snippet to one which has added `tag_` to each variable pair, but it looks like like `{first_page}`,`{pagination_url}`,`{previous_page}` etc are not working with that trick.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the variable pairs are prepended with "tag_" :)

This is what your code should look like:

```
{tag_paginate}
    <ul class="pagination">
    {tag_pagination_links}
    {first_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}">First</a></li>
    {/first_page}
    {previous_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}">&laquo; Previous</a></li>
    {/previous_page}
    {page}
        <li{if current_page} class="active"{/if}><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
    {/page}
    {next_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}">Next &raquo;</a></li>
    {/next_page}
    {last_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}">Last</a></li>
    {/last_page}
    {/tag_pagination_links}
    </ul>
{/tag_paginate}
```

Comment: `{previous_page}`, `{next_page}` `{current_page}` and `{total_pages}` from your example still are not working. Just creates some garbage http://awesomescreenshot.com/0663w4e75e

Comment: Well, it looks like you need to add `tag_` to all mentioned variables above to get your example to work.

Comment: What version of EE and Tag are you using? Is your `{exp:tag:entries}` wrapped in other tags, eg. {exp:channel:entries}, Stash tags, etc? Perhaps that affects parsing?

Comment: EE 2.7.3 and Tag 4.2.5 and `{exp:tag:entries}` is wrapped by the `{exp:switchee}`. Also take a look at http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26739/solspace-tag-display-entries-for-multiple-tags

Comment: And if the `{exp:tag:entries}` code is alone on a template, without any other tags such as `{exp:switchee}`, does it make a difference. Haven't had the chance to try Switchee much.